# Does SFSafariViewController and Safari web browser share cookies and Web-storage completely?

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, safari, sfsafariviewcontroller

Hi i'm having issues with using **SFSafariViewController**. What i'm trying to achieve is get in app browsing experience as close as **Safari** browsing. So that user don't feel any difference weather he is in Safari or inside the app.

This works well with most of the famous sites. But few sites does give broken experience and i'm trying to find out reason behind this.

**As Per apple It shares cookies and other website data with Safari.**

For example is if there is a shopping site and if user adds a product to cart within the app; It has to reflect in safari too. But it's not the case for few of sites.

Why is this happening, is this the problem from these sites, or I am missing something?

Thanks
cheers

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Seems like a bug of SFSafariViewController.

Comment: I need to read cookies from Safari app to inside my app. Is it possible?